# Playing a .mov file without UIWebView or MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video file with the .mov extension. It is not playing the video in my MPMoviePlayerController.  I need to play this type of file in my application. Is it possible to play a video file without using MPMoviePlayerController or UIWebView?

Please anyone suggest me in this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You absolutely should be able to play a .mov vidio file within MPMoviePlayerController.  Is your Xcode console giving you any indication of what the error might be?  Is the file on a remote server or built into the app?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks for your response. It is playing only audio is coming vedio did not see anything. Mainly at this situation i need to play file without using MPMoviePlayerCOntroller. Is it possible? Please can you suggest me

Comment: do you *want* to see the video or only play the audio from the .mov file?

Comment: Actually my main requirement is playing an video file in iphone without using MPMOviePlayerController or WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it directly before, but take a look at the [AVPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530).

Under the "Overview", you'll see:

> You use an AVPlayer object to implement controllers and user
>   interfaces for single- or multiple-item playback. The multiple-item
>   case supports advanced behaviors.

If you look at the [AV Foundation Programming guide (linked here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188), you'll see Apple builds the Media Player upon AV foundation.

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion i will refer now about AVPlayer class

Comment: I would be really surprised if `AVPlayer` has different results from `MPMoviePlayerController` (which actually relies upon `AVPlayer` internally) when it comes to CODEC compatibility.

Comment: well yes, I know that @Till... but the original poster wants to "go deeper", so hopefully I've set him off on the right direction to get whatever he's trying to do in place.